# OpenGL only utilizing the last initialized sprite's positional data

Tags: opengl, c++, graphics-programming

I'm currently creating a 2d fighting game utilizing OpenGL and I have run into a problem where OpenGL is only drawing at my last initialized sprite position, regardless of how many sprites I initialize and try and draw. Even when I initialize a sprite1 and sprite2 but only draw sprite1, sprite2 is what will still be drawn. It starts with my sprite class where I initialize where on the screen I want my image as well as what image to use:

Sprite.cpp

```
 Init(int screenCoordinateX, int screenCoordinateY, uint imageWidth, unsigned int imageHeight, std::string imageFilePath)
{
    //casting to float since GLSL shader variables vec2,3,4 require vertex data to be in floats
    this->x = static_cast<float>(x);
    this->y = static_cast<float>(y);
    this->width = static_cast<float>(width);
    this->height = static_cast<float>(height);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vboID);

    Blz::Graphics::GLTexture texture(imageFilePath);
    this->texture = texture;

    float halfWidth = this->width / 2;

    //Setting sprite origin at bottom middle of image by subtracting half width 
    this->vertexData.at(0).SetPosition(glm::vec3{ this->x + (this->width - halfWidth), this->y + this->height, 0.0f });//Top right corner
    this->vertexData.at(1).SetPosition(glm::vec3{ this->x - halfWidth, this->y + height, 0.0f });//Top left corner
    this->vertexData.at(2).SetPosition(glm::vec3{ this->x - halfWidth, this->y, 0.0f });//Bottom left corner
    this->vertexData.at(3).SetPosition(glm::vec3{ this->x - halfWidth, this->y, 0.0f });//Bottom left corner
    this->vertexData.at(4).SetPosition(glm::vec3{ this->x + (this->width - halfWidth), this->y, 0.0f });//Bottom right corner
    this->vertexData.at(5).SetPosition(glm::vec3{ this->x + (this->width - halfWidth), this->y + this->height, 0.0f });//Top right corner

    this->vertexData.at(0).SetUV(glm::vec2{ 1.0f, 1.0f });
    this->vertexData.at(1).SetUV(glm::vec2{ 0.0f, 1.0f });
    this->vertexData.at(2).SetUV(glm::vec2{ 0.0f, 0.0f });
    this->vertexData.at(3).SetUV(glm::vec2{ 0.0f, 0.0f });
    this->vertexData.at(4).SetUV(glm::vec2{ 1.0f, 0.0f });
    this->vertexData.at(5).SetUV(glm::vec2{ 1.0f, 1.0f });

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (sizeof(Vector3D) * this->vertexData.size()), &this->vertexData.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vector3D), (void*)offsetof(Vector3D, position));
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vector3D), (void*)offsetof(Vector3D, textureCoordinates));

    //Unbind 
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

I then try and render sprites passed in to renderer like so:

Renderer.cpp

```
void Renderer::Draw(Sprite& sprite)
{
    glm::mat4 orthoProjection = glm::ortho(0.0f, static_cast<sfloat>(1024), 0.0f, static_cast<sfloat>(768));
    GLuint transformationMatrixUniformLocation = this->shaderProgram.GetUniformLocation("transformationMatrix");

    glUniformMatrix4fv(transformationMatrixUniformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &(orthoProjection[0][0]));

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sprite.texture.id);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sprite.vboID);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

I here is my main.cpp where I begin to call everything:

```
int main() 
{
    Blz::Graphics::Renderer renderer;
    Blz::Window window;
    Blz::Input input;
    Scene scene;

    window.Initialize();
    renderer.Init();

    Sprite sprite1;
    sprite.Init(900, 300, 200, 200, "CharImage.png");

    Sprite sprite2;
    sprite2.Init(100, 100, 200, 200, "CharImage.png");

    while (!input.IsKeyPressed(SDLK_ESCAPE))
    {
        window.ClearBuffers();

        renderer.Draw(sprite1);

        window.SwapBuffers();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So even though I ask for sprite1 to be drawn, only sprite2's position at 100x 100y gets drawn to the screen. Even if I manually try and enter a vboID of 1 (which is the vboID of sprite1) within renderer.cpp, it still draws sprite2's position. What am I doing wrong?

Here are my Shaders if necessary:

VertexShader.glsl

```
#version 430

in vec3 vertexPosition;
in vec2 textCoord;

out vec2 TextureCoord;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;

void main()
{
    vec4 position = vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0f);
    gl_Position = transformationMatrix * position;
    TextureCoord = textCoord;
};
```

FragmentShader.glsl

```
#version 430

out vec4 daColor;
in vec2 TextureCoord;

uniform sampler2D basicTexture;

void main()
{
    vec4 texel = texture(basicTexture, TextureCoord);
    daColor = texel;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `glVertexAttribPointer` *in* `Sprite.Init`. So it makes sense that the last sprite initiated will be rendered, since that sprite's vertices are being pointed to.

Instead, one way to handler this is to create a method for `Sprite` called `Render` (I don't write in C++, so please excuse any case errors!). Call this method in your render loop, and call `glVertexAttribPointer` in the method. Then, the order in which you initiate the sprites won't matter.